# Portable Class Library in MVC 4 / Razor with Visual Studio 2012 RC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, .net-4.5, portable-class-library

since working with Visual Studio 2012 RC we get an HttpCompileException when using a class out of an portable class library (.net 4.5 & metro profile) within a razor view.

Exception: (german to english translated on google, sorry)

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005):     
c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET        
Files\root\1995167a\126b7c4d\App_Web_index.cshtml.1fbcdbb1.zaniprm5.0.cs(29):

error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is not in a referenced assembly is 
defined. Add a reference to the Assembly "System.Runtime, Version = 4.0.0.0, 
Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a" added.   

at
System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()   
System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()    
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
...
```

Solution structure:

- Portable Class Library (.net 4.5 & metro profile)

  - public class User { ... }
- MVC 4 (.net 4.5)

  - Reference to Portable Class Library
  - Razor-View

    - @model User

Since Visual Studio 2012 RC adding reference "System.Runtime" is not possible any more.

Comment: As a workaround, can you change the portable class library to target Silverlight 5 in addition to .NET 4.5 and Metro style?

Answer (score 60):

In the Views\Web.config file, add the following code under the `<system.web>` section:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

There are a bunch of other assemblies you may also need to reference, depending on what types your portable code is using.  You can either add each one as you encounter the error, or add the full list of assemblies in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades`.

Comment: This solved a similar issue for me using System.Collections.Immutable

Comment: Depending on what you are doing in your project, you may also need to add the very same line to the root `Web.Config`

Comment: @LukePuplett kind of late, but here's a good explanation http://www.lyalin.com/2014/04/25/the-type-system-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-reference-mvc-pcl-issue/

Comment: @WetNoodles Thanks. Funny, if you follow the link in the blog back to SO its my question.