# System.Runtime 4.0.10.0 missing on Server 2012r2 after website upgrade to MVC5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Website works fine locally on Windows 8.1, but after publishing to Server 2012R2, certain pages get an error saying the following:

Exception message: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\b306803a\3271e75d\App_Web_sign-in.cshtml.1d427dc2.p4pq8o_l.0.cs(30): error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I can't work out what or how is referencing that System.Runtime dll. What might I be missing and how might I track it down?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16228029/809357 ?

Comment: Found the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897712/portable-class-library-in-mvc-4-razor-with-visual-studio-2012-rc

Answer (score 0):

> I can't work out what or how is referencing that System.Runtime dll.
>   What might I be missing and how might I track it down?

I am glad that you mentioned your OS is Windows 2012. The System.Runtime dll file is distributed as part of the [Windows 8 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx).

See more explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/14517992/3918598